# A heuristic approach to solve a MILP problem?

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming, metaheuristics, heuristics

I have the following optimization problem which is a MILP. I can solve it with a MILP solver. This one I posted here [Is there a heuristic approach to the MILP problem?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/2964/is-there-a-heuristic-approach-to-the-milp-problem)

Since I have an additional but very important constraint, I am putting it as a new post. I am looking for a heuristic approach to solve this problem. Any Hint?

\begin{alignat}{2}\min_t&\quad t\\\text{s.t.}&\quad d_{c}-t\le \sum_{n=1}^{N} B_{n,c}x_{n}\le d_{c}+t,\quad&\forall c\in\{1,2,\cdots,C\}\\&\quad\sum_{n=1}^{N} x_n = M\\
&\quad x_n\le M y_n, \quad\forall n\\
&\quad\sum_{n=1}^N y_n \le 3
\end{alignat}

### **VERY IMPORTANT**

As this a part of another problem, I found that this is not serving what I actually needed. I want to put one more constraint. There can be only a given number of non-zero $x_n$, for example, for the previous example, let say, we can have a maximum $3$ non-zero $x_n$s.

where

- $B$ is a binary matrix of size $N\times C$
- $d$ is a known vector of the positive numbers of size $1\times C$
- $M$ is a known parameter
- $x_n$ is an optimization variable (integer variable, $x_n\ge 0$, $x_n\in\{0,1,2,3,\cdots,M\}$)
- $y_n$ is a binary variable
- $t$ is also an optimization variable (integer/continuous)

@prubin has suggested a reformulation of the problem as

If we set $S_c = \{n : B_{n,c}=1\}$, we can rewrite the problem as $$\begin{align*}
\min_{t} & \quad t\\
\text{s.t.} & \quad\left|\sum_{n\in S_{c}}x_{n}-d_{c}\right|\le t,\quad\forall c\in\{1,2,\cdots,C\}\\
 & \quad\sum_{n=1}^{N}x_{n}=M.
\end{align*}$$A simple greedy heuristic is to start with $x_n=0\,\forall n$ and, in each iteration, bump one of the $x$ variables up by 1, selecting the $x_n$ that most improves (or least degrades) $t$, until the equality constraint is satisfied.

Comment: The heuristic I previously suggested could be adapted here, by adding a restriction that once three different x variables have been bumped, you are limited to using just those three (or however many the limit on nonzeroes is). I don't know that it would be a very good heuristic, though.

Answer (score 5):

Introduce binary variables $y_n$ and constraints \begin{align}
x_n &\le M y_n &&\text{for all $n$}\\
\sum_n y_n &\le 3
\end{align}

Comment: For once, $M$ is actually the right value to use for big-M. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modification of the bumping heuristic, assuming that you are limited to using $K$ of the $x$ variables (so $K=3$ in your example):

1. Select $K$ distinct values of the index $n$ randomly.
2. Apply the bumping heuristic, but limit it to bumping those $K$ variables. Note that the heuristic may not bump all of them.
3. Record the new solution if it beats the previous incumbent.
4. Repeat *ad nauseum*.